# Add "Save" button and Approval Workflow in InfoPath

Tags: workflow, infopath, approval, save-as-template

I've built a SP list where items are added via an InfoPath form. My form has mandatory fields and I want to add a "Save" button that will allow users to save the form without submitting it.

Related to the above I want to add an approval workflow where after the form is submitted, it's sent to an "Approver" to either Approve or Reject the submission. Any help here? I'm not a developer, so usuing any out of the box functionality in SP is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

In InfoPath, a save is typically the same as a submit: both save the form to SharePoint. The typical pattern is to add a "status" field to the form. Give it a default value of something like "saved". Then, add two buttons to the form. One will submit the form as-is, so the status field will still be "saved". For the other button, add an additional action to set the status field to "submitted", and then submit the form to sharepoint. For the approval, create a SharePoint designer workflow, which has an approval action (in the "2010" workflow engine, which is still available in newer versions of SharePoint)

The first step of the workflow will be to check the value of the status field: if it's saved, end the workflow. If it's "submitted", then go on to the next step and start the approval.

btw, I mention SharePoint designer because you mentioned infopath. Both tools are older at this point. If you're in SharePoint online, certainly do the above with PowerApps and Flow.